# Clear Graphic memory

Tags: intel-graphics

I have an Intel(R)High Definition Graphics 4000.Now I am all out on  memory.But I recently bought ac syndicate,This game lags.I am not that rich to afford another graphic card.So can anyone please tell me how to clear my graphic memory.

Comment: You reboot your computer.  It sounds like you don't have enough VRAM, if thats the case, that is a limitation of the hardware itself.

Comment: You may need to buy an external graphics card because for AC syndicate, an integrated HD 4000 will not cut it.

Answer (score 3):

VRAM will clear itself (Unless there is a memory leak in the game!). The only way to forcably clear the VRAM is to reboot your machine.

**However...**

Looking at the requirements for the game at [Can you run it](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/assassins-creed-syndicate/12971) It appears you would require 2GB VRAM as a minimum to play the game confortably. The Intel HD 4000 can have anywhere between 256MB to 1GB depending on the total amount of RAM in your machine. On some desktop Motherboard you can alter the amount of Video Memory dedicated to the Intel HD chipset in accordance to the amount of RAM you have (This can be achieved in the [BIOS](http://www.pvladov.com/2013/10/increase-intel-hd-graphics-dedicated-video-memory.html)).

In addition to this, The game will require an Nvidia 660 Graphics card to play comfortably. and the benchmark scoring for the Intel HD 4000 doesn't come close to this unfortunately. So, in summary, you are restriced by your hardware and would require a more powerful graphics chipset.

This being said, It may be worth trying to turn all the graphics settings of the game to low and reducing the resolution. The game may look horrible, but you ***may*** be able to play it!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks but i think it really hard and money consuming to add a graphic card to a laptop